# Saving Order of a Dataframe to HDFS

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

### **Input Data:**

```
key,date,value    
10,20180701,a10    
11,20180702,a11    
12,20180702,a12    
13,20180702,a13    
14,20180702,a14    
15,20180702,a15    
16,20180702,a16
17,20180702,a17    
18,20180702,a18    
19,20180702,a19    
1 ,20180701,a1     
2 ,20180701,a2     
3 ,20180701,a3     
4 ,20180701,a4     
5 ,20180701,a5     
6 ,20180701,a6 
7 ,20180701,a7 
8 ,20180701,a8 
9 ,20180701,a9
```

Code

```
val rawData=sc.textFile(.....).
val datadf:DataFrame=rawData.toDF
```

After reading the data into DF with columns `key,data,value`

```
datadf.coalesce(1).orderBy(desc("key")).drop(col("key")).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("date").text("hdfs://path/")
```

I am trying to order the column by column key and drop the same column before saving to hdfs (into a single file for each day).
I am not able to preserve the order in the outputfiles.
if i am not using coalesce the order is preserved but multiple files are getting generated.

**Output:**

```
/20180701/part-xxxxxxx.txt

        a1
        a9
        a6
        a4
        a5
        a3
        a7
        a8
        a2
        a10
/20180702/part-xxxxxxx.txt  

        a18
        a12
        a13
        a19
        a15
        a16
        a17
        a11
        a14
```

**Expected OP:**

```
/20180701/part-xxxxxxx.txt

        a1
        a2
        a3
        a4
        a5
        a6
        a7
        a8
        a9
        a10
/20180702/part-xxxxxxx.txt      

        a11
        a12
        a13
        a14
        a15
        a16
        a17
        a18
        a19
```

Comment: What is the type of "key" field?

Comment: type of the key field is string

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you started (This is using Spark 2.1) :-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
val schema = new StructType().add($"key".int).add($"date".string).add($"value".string)
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("header","true").csv("source.txt")
df.coalesce(1).orderBy("key").drop("key").write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("date").csv("hdfs://path/")
```